Getting "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'" error when creating variable from output
I'm looking at using Ansible with the hpe.ilo collection to automate the selection of disks for the creation of logical disks in RAID arrays.  I've found through testing that using CapacityMiB rather than CapacityGB gives a more accurate size.  However, when attempting to extract this and the disk location from the hpe.ilo.ilo_storage module and inject this as variables into the final task, I get the error shown in the title.
Pretty sure I'm converting it to an integer but I can't figure out where it's breaking.
Here the code:
---

  - name: Disk Picker
    hosts: localhost
    become: False
    gather_facts: False
    vars:
      os_disks: 2
      os_disk_size: 400000
      os_disks: []
      data_disks: []

    tasks:
      - name: Get Disk Info
        hpe.ilo.ilo_storage:
          category: Systems
          command: GetPhysicalDrives
          baseuri: x.x.x.x
          username: username
          password: password
        register: disks

      - name: Loop Disk Info
        debug:
          msg:
            - "{{ item.CapacityMiB }}"
            - "{{ item.Location }}"
        loop: "{{ disks.ilo_storage.GetPhysicalDrives.msg.physical_drives.array_controller_0 }}"

      - name: Capture Lowest Capacity Disk for OS
        set_fact:
          os_disk_size: "{{ item.CapacityMiB }}"
        loop:
          "{{ disks.ilo_storage.GetPhysicalDrives.msg.physical_drives.array_controller_0 }}"
        when:  item.CapacityMiB | int <= os_disk_size | int

      - name: Output OS disk size
        debug:
          msg: "os_disk_size = {{ os_disk_size }}"

      - name: get OS Disks
        set_fact:
          os_disks: "{{ os_disks | default([]) + [{ 'Location': item.Location,'CapacityMiB': item.CapacityMiB }] }}"
        loop: "{{ disks.ilo_storage.GetPhysicalDrives.msg.physical_drives.array_controller_0 }}"
        when: item.CapacityMiB <= os_disk_size | int

      - name: Output Disk Variables
        debug:
          var: os_disks

      - name: Output Disk Location
        debug:
          msg:
            - "{{ os_disks[0].Location }}"
            - "{{ os_disks[1].CapacityMiB }}"
            - '["{{ os_disks[0].Location }}", "{{ os_disks[1].Location }}"]'

      - name: Convert Disk Size - MiB to GB
        set_fact:
          mib_to_gb: "{{ os_disks[1].CapacityMiB/1024|int }}"

      - name: Output Real Disk Size
        set_fact:
          real_disk_size: "{{ (mib_to_gb|string).split('.')[0]|int }}"

      - name: Output real disk size
        debug:
          msg: "{{ real_disk_size }}"

      - name: Create logical drives with particular physical drives
        hpe.ilo.ilo_storage:
          category: Systems
          command: CreateLogicalDrivesWithParticularPhysicalDrives
          baseuri: x.x.x.x
          username: username
          password: password
          raid_details:
            - LogicalDriveName: LD1
              Raid: Raid1
              CapacityGB: '{{ real_disk_size }}'
              DataDrives: '["{{ os_disks[0].Location }}", "{{ os_disks[1].Location }}"]

Actual Result
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'.
Expected:
  - name: Create logical drives with particular physical drives
    hpe.ilo.ilo_storage:
      category: Systems
      command: CreateLogicalDrivesWithParticularPhysicalDrives
      baseuri: x.x.x.x
      username: username
      password: password
      raid_details:
        - LogicalDriveName: LD1
          Raid: Raid1
          CapacityGB: 223
          DataDrives: ["1I:1:1", "1I:1:2"]

Traceback
"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1714484961.2196221-218458-39334877462429/AnsiballZ_ilo_storage.py", line 107, in \n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File "/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1714484961.2196221-218458-39334877462429/AnsiballZ_ilo_storage.py", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File "/home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1714484961.2196221-218458-39334877462429/AnsiballZ_ilo_storage.py", line 47, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.hpe.ilo.plugins.modules.ilo_storage', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible_collections.hpe.ilo.plugins.modules.ilo_storage', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 224, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File "/tmp/ansible_hpe.ilo.ilo_storage_payload_fqkaedoz/ansible_hpe.ilo.ilo_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/hpe/ilo/plugins/modules/ilo_storage.py", line 423, in \n  File "/tmp/ansible_hpe.ilo.ilo_storage_payload_fqkaedoz/ansible_hpe.ilo.ilo_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/hpe/ilo/plugins/modules/ilo_storage.py", line 400, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_hpe.ilo.ilo_storage_payload_fqkaedoz/ansible_hpe.ilo.ilo_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/hpe/ilo/plugins/module_utils/ilo_oem_utils.py", line 1538, in create_logical_drives_with_particular_physical_drives\n  File "/tmp/ansible_hpe.ilo.ilo_storage_payload_fqkaedoz/ansible_hpe.ilo.ilo_storage_payload.zip/ansible_collections/hpe/ilo/plugins/module_utils/ilo_oem_utils.py", line 1253, in check_physical_drives\nTypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'\n",
"module_stdout": "",
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
"rc": 1

Please [edit] to provide the full traceback.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Added the traceback

Does You can't convert a string var into integer with | int in set_fact, since set_fact will be always a string answer your question? Just use CapacityGB: '{{ real_disk_size | int }}' instead and you can remove the obsolete | int in the fact settings of mib_to_gb: "{{ os_disks[1].CapacityMiB/1024|int }}" and real_disk_size: "{{ (mib_to_gb|string).split('.')[0]|int }}".
